# Get data from text file and send an email in table format

Tags: powershell

I have a text file with data as below

```
ServerName1|Status1
ServerName2|Status2
.
.
.
ServerNamen|Statusn
```

I have to email the above text in table format using PowerShell. SMTP is already configured.

Email is to be in table format of the above.

Comment: `Import-Csv -Delimiter '|' | ConvertTo-Html`

Answer (score 2):

As [hinted by Ansgar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374940/get-data-from-text-file-and-send-an-email-in-table-format/36375236#comment60367991_36374940), you can utilize [`Import-Csv`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849891.aspx) to read the text file into objects, and then [`ConvertTo-Html`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849944(v=wps.630).aspx) to produce the table for the email:

```
$StatusTable = Import-Csv .\status.txt -Delimiter '|' -Header Server,Status | ConvertTo-Html -As Table
Send-MailMessage -Body $StatusTable -BodyAsHtml ...
```